# Unable to set data from a Dialog on a TextView

Tags: android, dialog, textview

I read data from a Dialog but I'm unable to set that data on a TextView.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please elaborate on what exactly you are doing there. Show me some code and a stack trace please.

Answer (score 1):

```
// We can't imagine what you are doing wrong, without seeing your source code.  
TextView facePalm = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.youtextview);
facePalm.setText("Like Octavian Damiean said you should improve your question.");
```

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: This answers the question of how to set data on a `TextView`. And I don't like adding code in the comments. Octavian has already left feedback for the author, so your suggestion is superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

When you customize a dialog, you should do it like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
final View layoutview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rootview, null);
final TextView title=(TextView) layoutview.findViewById(R.id.text);
```